# Runnable running only one time

Tags: android, runnable

I need a task to be executed many times, until certain condition is met. The code:

```
handler = new Handler();
runnableCode = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       doThings();
   }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 200);
```

Method doThings:

```
private void doThings(){
    //conditions are met
    stopRunnable();

}
```

Method stopRunnable:

```
private void stopRunnable(){
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnableCode);
}
```

This way, doThings() method is only executing one time. How should I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Use a `Timer` with a `TimerTask`: `timer.schedule(timerTask, delay, period)`. Do your stuff into the the `run` method of the `TimerTask`. When finished call `Timer.cancel()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try :

```
handler=new Handler();
runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    doThings();
    if(condition){
        handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 200);
    }
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 200);
```

Method stopRunnable:

```
private void stopRunnable(){
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

Comment: Doing that, even after stopRunnable() the runnable keeps running.

Comment: What is the condition in the `if` statement ?

Answer (score 0):

PostDelayed tells it to call the unnable in 200ms.  If you want it to be called again in another 200ms, your runnable has to post itself to the Handler again.

Answer (score 0):

this is easy ,Recursively invoke your Runnable like below:

```
handler=new Handler();

            runnableCode = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    doThings();
                    // just add this line 
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 200);


                }

            };
    handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Kotlin

```
 fun handler() {


    handler = Handler()
    var count: Int = 0
    runnabl = Runnable {
        kotlin.run {
            count++
            Toast.makeText(this,"$count",10000).show()
         //      Route.mToast(this, "hello +$count")
         //must add this 
            handler.postDelayed(runnabl, 10000) //--------repeat each interval 
        }
    }

    count++
    //must add this 
    handler.postDelayed(runnabl, 2000)      //----------------starthere------
};

lateinit var runnabl: Runnable
lateinit var handler: Handler
```

It is recusrsive operation so you must add handler. Postdelayed in inside run and outside please notify before downvote, so I can modify the answer.